# I am assuming that this is related to this plugin. Does anyone know how I can get rid of this?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, payment-gateway

Notice: Function get_billing_address_1 was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/mojuri/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/mojuri/templates/content/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, WC_Shortcodes::checkout, WC_Shortcodes::shortcode_wrapper, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::output, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::order_pay, wc_get_template, include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/order-receipt.php'), do_action('woocommerce_receipt_paygate'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_PayGate->receipt_page, WC_PayGate->generate_ccavenue_form, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 5831

Answer (score 0):

You might want to update the woocommerce plugin of your website, just to restore all the changes/error that you have made from modifying directly to the plugin. You can also just reinstall the woocommerce, by uploading a new woocommerce plugin without the need of uninstalling the plugin in your website.